# Python passing instance methods as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, self, instance-methods

I want to pass an instance method as an argument to a function that applies it to an instance it internally has. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Have you *tried* anything that makes you think it isn't possible?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After being unable to find the answer sufficiently fast, I tried it myself and decided to make this post in the Q&A style to make it easier to find. Because I answered my own question, I made the body of the question short as most people only ever read the answer anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python object methods are functions that expect the instance as their first parameter.   Calling `myInstance.method(x)` is similar to calling `type(myInstance).method(myinstance,x)`

An example of how this works can be seen when calling the map function.

```
L = [ [1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9] ]

print(*map(list.pop,L)) # 3 5 9

print(L) # [[1, 2], [4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

We passed a method of the `list` class as a parameter to `map()` which handles the lists in `L` internally. So the map() function is applying a method on list instances that it has internally.

To do the same thing, you can define a method or function that expects a method as a parameter and add your object instance as the first parameter when calling it:

```
def apply(method):
    myInstance = list()
    method(myInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily doable in Python by passing the method as a `callable` and by passing `self` as the first argument of this callable.

Consider a simple class `Foo` where each instance keeps an integer value with a function `bar` that returns the value with 1 added to it.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val: int):
        self.val = val

    def bar(self) -> int:
        return self.val + 1
```

When externally using this class, it is normal to write `Foo(3).bar()`. In this instance, `Foo(3)` is an instance of `Foo` and is passed as the `self` parameter in `bar()`.
Note that it is perfectly legal to instead write `Foo.bar(Foo(3))`. While you should generally avoid this, it is useful when you want to pass a function instead of the instance to a method.

Consider the function `print_res` that receives a `callable` (a method, a function) that is applied to a specific instance of `Foo` and prints the result.

```
def print_res(fun):
    one = Foo(1)
    print(fun(one))  # Pass the instance as the 'self' argument in the given callable.
```

Calling `print_res(Foo.bar)` then returns `2`.

Passing an arbitrary callable won't work. Passing `print` for example, transforms `print(fun(one))` into `print(print(one)`. Obviously, this is unintended behaviour. This is why you should consider adding type annotations to indicate the desired arguments and result type of the callable.

```
from typing import Callable

def print_res(fun: Callable[[Foo], int]):
    one = Foo(1)
    print(fun(one))  # Pass the instance as the 'self' argument in the given callable.
```

This will indicate to the user that it should be called with something that takes an instance of `Foo` and returns an `int`.